# Setting value of hiddenfield with Jquery and retrieve value server side

Tags: jquery, hiddenfield

My scenario is this. User clicks on button and a modal dialog appears with a checkboxlist. When the user makes their selections and clicks 'ok' in client click event I want to set a hiddenfield with the list of values the user selected. The user continues with rest of form and clicks another button to submit the whole form. From code behind (button Click event) I need to access this list of values that was stuffed into the hiddenfield to save to DB.

ClienclickEvent code

```
 function onOk() {
        var selectedItems = [];
        $("[id*=CategoryCheckboxList] input:checked").each(function () {
            selectedItems.push(this.value);
        });
        //stuff the values in the hidden field for later postback
        $("#hiddenCategoryHash").value = selectedItems; //appears to work, no errors
        $("#debugcat").text(selectedItems); //stuff into a div for testing (works)
        $("#dbg").text = selectedItems;   //attempted to stuff in Textbox. FAIL
        }
```

It should be noted that I have also tried this with an html input control and using request.form to retrieve the values that way, but does not work either. Do I have the right approach here? Should I go about this in a different manner?

Here is the markup

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenCategoryHash" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"   />
<asp:TextBox ID="dbg" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input type="hidden" name="conf4" value="test" />
```

Lastly here is the code behind

```
xfer.IsActive = True
    xfer.IsDiscontinued = False
    Dim hiddenval = Request.Form("hiddenCategoryHash")
    Dim test = hiddenCategoryHash.Value
    Dim debugdiv = Request.Form("debugcat")
    xfer.CategoryIDhash = hiddenval
    dc.Transfers.InsertOnSubmit(xfer)
    dc.SubmitChanges()
```

Thank you for all your suggestions. As it turns out I had to grab the full clientID of the hidden control in my jquery selector, like so:  $("#<%= hiddenCategoryHash.ClientID %>").val(selectedItems);.

Comment: this syntax is wrong: $("#dbg").text = selectedItems; should be $("#dbg").text(selectedItems);

Comment: Thank you, just useless testing code though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the value of the textfield use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$("#dbg").val(selectedItems.join(','));
```

Same for the hiddlen field also

```
$("#hiddenCategoryHash").val(selectedItems.join(','))
```

Comment: hiddenCategoryHash is the element I need to work. This is the actual hidden field that I am attempting to utilize. According to msdn docs the hiddenfield is exactly what I need to use to do what I trying to do

Comment: @DoImagine same case there also, you need to use `.val()`

Comment: Tried  $("#hiddenCategoryHash").val(selectedItems); and it still is empty on submit. The selectedItems is already a comma seperated list so I don't need a join, correct?

Comment: @DoImagine Can you add an `alert($("#hiddenCategoryHash").val())` after setting the value

Comment: @DoImagine can you try `alert($("#hiddenCategoryHash").length)`

Comment: that means there is no elemetn with id `hiddenCategoryHash`

Comment: Except that it is there. The fields are at the top of the content page. I just added a label and tried to use it the same way (display:none) and it gave me the same undefined error.. I even moved them to the bottom of the content page and it makes no difference. Not sure why they are coming up as undefined.. This part is client side so lifecycle isn't culprit..

Comment: Can you type `$("#hiddenCategoryHash").length` in your browser console and see the result

Comment: Also inspect the html using browser tool to see that element exists and id is properly set

Comment: Well as it turns out I had to select the client id of the element like so:  $("#<%= hiddenCategoryHash.ClientID %>").val(selectedItems); Isn't .net supposed to keep track of those for you? :) Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function onOk() 
      {
            selectedItems = [];
            $("input[id*=CategoryCheckboxList]:checked").each(function(){
               selectedItems.push($(this).val())
            });
            $("#hiddenCategoryHash").val(selectedItems);
            $("#debugcat").text(selectedItems);
            $("#dbg").val(selectedItems);
     }
```

if you want to join the values you can use selectedItems.join(',')

Comment: The selected items is correct and in a comma delimited format already as verified by alert and the $("#debugcat").text(selectedItems); dumps it to a div on the page and I see it fine there.

Comment: $("#dbg").text change to  $("#dbg").val, because  $("#dbg") is text box not div..so  val() will work